# Android - Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, session, authentication

I've got some problem implementing Facebook login.

If I create the Facebook object with an existing api key,i got some intresting thing. If I run the activity on a real device, after clicking on the button, appears Facebbok, it loads, but before I could see the wall it disappears. If I try to run the activity in emulator, facebook's isSessionValid returns true, so seems like I managed to log in. But login screen doesn't appears, and even any view /webview or facebook app/ does not appears.

If I create Facebook object without api key (Facebook facebook = new Facebook("APIKEY");)
both on the phone and the emulator a webview appears with facebook login screen, if i was logged out, or with the facebook page if i was logged in. In this case I can't get any information about the session, so isSessionValid always returns with false . But in this case, at least I can see login page and facebook actually.

```
fButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.login);
    fButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            facebook.authorize(FbLogin.this,
                    new Facebook.DialogListener() {

                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "fberror", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        public void onError(DialogError e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "dialogerror", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();

                        }

                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) { 

                        }

                        public void onCancel() { // TODO Auto-generated
                                                    // method stub

                        }
                    });


        }
    });
```

and i would like to check the session with the following method:

```
void check(){
    if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        System.out.println("IN");
    } else {
        System.out.println("OUT");
    }
}
```

I thought maybe i've got some problem with the api key, but i didn't got any message refers to it

Sorry for my poor english :S